# Android studio error highlight

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

please help me remove this annoying squares ! I can't find this option anywhere :(!
Program: android studio

Comment: What error do you see when you hover your mouse over the red squiggles?

Comment: depending on the error I made(here it's header expected). I don't care about my error I just don't like seeing those squares. The wave underlines are enough to tell me that I have a problem so I don't need the square.

Comment: when I press right click on it, it shows:
http://i.imgur.com/NwjxSnT.png
when I choose customize highlight level:
http://i.imgur.com/tVpxwpY.png

even if I jump into **configure inspections**, and **uncheck** the red inspection (or other colors), it's still showing that annoying squares:
http://i.imgur.com/tVpxwpY.png

Comment: The red square on the right indicates that there is a problem with your source code. Turning it off means that you are ignoring the problem rather than fixing it. You need to hover over the red squigglies on the left (in the editor) to see what the actual problem is.

Comment: thanks for the help <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the coloured squares (Also known as inspections) you either need to solve the reason Android Studio has alerted you to that piece of code with a warning/error; or disable the inspections.

To disable one off/singular inspections:

1. Go to the part of the code which shows the warning/error
2. Press alt + enter on keyboard
3. Click "disable inspection"
4. That specific inspection should disappear

To disable all inspections:

1. Go to settings, then editor, then inspections
2. You should see a list of all inspections, here you can edit what ones you want, and how they behave
3. To turn off an inspection, un-check its tick-box to the right side of the list
4. To turn off all inspections, just un-check all tick-boxes

Comment: OMG! I didn't notice that every option (that has tick-box) is expandable. Thanks for the help ^^

Comment: @MohanndSubbah Note that disabling an inspection will also remove the red squiggles in the editor as well as the red box in the scroll bar area that you are concerned about. So you are effectively ignoring the problem rather than fixing it.